# Sending message TVM_EDITLABEL fails

Tags: winapi

`TreeView_EditLabel(tv, item)` fails(returns zero).

`item` is valid, and is the only item in the treeview.

What's the problem? Is there some prerequisite? Or it just doesn't work?

I'm on Windows 10.

Here's a minimal reproducible example

```
#include <windowsx.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <assert.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Comctl32.lib")

HWND hTv;
HTREEITEM hItem;
auto className = L"someclass";

ATOM                MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance);
void                InitInstance(HINSTANCE, int);
LRESULT CALLBACK    WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPWSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    InitCommonControls();
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow);
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex{};

    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);

    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.lpszClassName = className;

    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}
void InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(className, L"", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 400, 400, 400, 400, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
    assert(hWnd);

    hTv = CreateWindowW(WC_TREEVIEW, L"Tree View", WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | TVS_HASLINES, 0, 0, 300, 300, hWnd, 0, 0, NULL);
    assert(hTv);
    {
        TVITEM tvi{};
        TVINSERTSTRUCT tvins{};
        tvi.mask = TVIF_TEXT;

        wchar_t name[] = L"item";
        tvi.pszText = name;

        tvins.item = tvi;
        hItem = TreeView_InsertItem(hTv, &tvins);
    }
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    SetFocus(hTv);
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_NOTIFY:
    {
        switch (reinterpret_cast<LPNMHDR>(lParam)->code)
        {
        case NM_CLICK:
            assert(TreeView_EditLabel(hTv, hItem));
            break;
        }
        break;
    }
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The requirements are [documented](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/commctrl/nf-commctrl-treeview_editlabel): *"The control must have the focus before you call this macro."*

Comment: How can `TreeView_EditLabel` return zero? It's a `void` type: `void TreeView_EditLabel(hwnd, hitem);`.

Comment: @adr All macros are documented to return `void`, unless manually updated. Like the [RGB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-rgb) macro, that clearly does return a value.

Comment: @IInspectable it does have focus. I'll put a minimal example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A tree-view control needs the [TVS_EDITLABELS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tree-view-control-window-styles) control style set to support editing labels of tree-view items.

You need to replace the tree-view control creation code

```cpp
hTv = CreateWindowW(
    WC_TREEVIEW,
    L"Tree View",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | TVS_HASLINES,
    0, 0, 300, 300,
    hWnd,
    0,
    0,
    NULL);
```

with this:

```cpp
hTv = CreateWindowW(
    WC_TREEVIEW,
    L"Tree View",
    WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER | TVS_HASLINES | TVS_EDITLABELS,
    0, 0, 300, 300,
    hWnd,
    0,
    0,
    NULL);
```

The [tree-view controls overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tree-view-controls) overview provides additional details under the section titled [tree-view label edition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/tree-view-controls#tree-view-label-editing).

Comment: But that way calling `TreeView_EditLabel` on `NM_CLICK` or `NM_DBLCLK` does nothing. So, without calling `TreeView_EditLabel`, it enters inline editing after a click after a slight delay. But if I want to enter editing right away and on `NM_DBLCLK`?

Comment: @adl This wasn't meant to replace all your code, just to enable your call to `TreeView_EditLabel` to succeed. If you want instant editing, you're still going to have to call `TreeView_EditLabel` from your [NM_CLICK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-click-tree-view) handler (note: *"Return nonzero to prevent the default processing"*). Also keep in mind that an `NM_DBLCLK` never arrives in isolation. There's *always* an `NM_CLICK` notification preceding it.

Comment: `case NM_CLICK: assert(TreeView_EditLabel(hTv, hItem)); return 0;`
results in nothing

Comment: It results in the `assert` no longer failing. And `return 0;` results in default processing, as written in my previous comment.

Comment: sorry, misread. But changing 0 to 1 changes nothing

Comment: Still, that's a different issue, that warrants its own question. This questions asked, why sending a `TVM_EDITLABEL` message resulted in receiving a `NULL` value, and this answer addresses that question.

Comment: Why is `TreeView_EditLabel()` inside of `assert()`? On a release build, `assert()` is a no-op, so `TreeView_EditLabel()` won't be called at all. If you want to assert on the return value, do that separately, eg: `case NM_CLICK: { HWND editWnd = TreeView_EditLabel(hTv, hItem); assert(editWnd != NULL); break; }`

Comment: @rem `assert` is your language-provided tool to verify conditions in a debug configuration. Why avoid it? Your proposed alternative just added 4 lines of code. That's not exactly the goal of a [mcve].

Comment: @IInspectable I did not say to avoid `assert`. I merely said that the call to `TreeView_EditLabel()` should be moved **outside** of the `assert` so that it is actually called regardless of whether a debug build or a release build is being compiled. In a release build, `assert(TreeView_EditLabel(...))` will not call `TreeView_EditLabel(...)`, but `editWnd = TreeView_EditLabel(...); assert(editWnd != NULL);` will.

Comment: @rem The effect of the `assert` macro is well understood. Can't you acknowledge the OP's attempt to produce a [mcve]?

Comment: @IInspectable "*The effect of the `assert` macro is well understood*" - obviously not by the OP or else the `NM_CLICK` code would not be written the way it is. "*Can't you acknowledge the OP's attempt to produce a [mcve]?*" - I do acknowledge it. But it has a bug (not related to the issue in question) that should be addressed once the issue is resolved so as not to cause a new issue later

Comment: @rem It does not have a bug. It has restrictions. And yes, you are correct, it should be addressed **once** the issue is resolved. Like, **after** the OP has received an answer to their question.

Comment: @IInspectable "*it does not have a bug*" - "Umm, why isn't my code doing anything in a release build? Oh, because it didn't get compiled in the first place!" Sounds like a bug to me. But whatever. I'm done arguing.

Comment: @rem Ok, great. I implemented your bug fix, and now my code no longer compiles in a release build. Doesn't sound like a bug fix to me. But whatever.

Comment: @IInspectable The code I showed would compile just fine in debug and release builds.

Comment: @IInspectable That is not an bug with `assert()` itself. When `assert()` is a no-op in a release build, indeed any code inside of it is ignored, which could lead to assigned variables being unreferenced, if no other code outside the `assert()` uses them. This is not an ERROR, it is a WARNING at best, and GodBolt is simply treating warnings as errors (`error C2220: the following warning is treated as an error`). Would you rather have a return value that is ignored, or the function call itself not being called at all? You didn't try the code in the context of an actual Windows compiler, did you?

Comment: @IInspectable To avoid that warning, you can type-cast `editWnd` to void`, eg: `HWND editWnd = TreeView_EditLabel(hTv, hItem); assert(editWnd != NULL); ((void)editWnd);`, or you can use the Win32 API's `DBG_UNREFERENCED_LOCAL_VARIABLE()` macro in `winnt.h`, eg: `HWND editWnd = TreeView_EditLabel(hTv, hItem); assert(editWnd != NULL); DBG_UNREFERENCED_LOCAL_VARIABLE(editWnd);`

Comment: @rem *"You didn't try the code in the context of an actual Windows compiler, did you?"* - Compiler Explorer displays the compiler and version used to compile. It's MSVC in this case. I would call that *"an actual Windows compiler"*, but then, that's just me. Now the question you are asking is: Would you rather have this bug or that bug? The answer is simple: Neither. In production code. An [mcve] is not production code. If you must know the rationale behind this particular code construct, leave a comment on the question, not this answer that doesn't contain, reference or promote its use.